# FastAPI Jinja2Templates - Error whie providing external directory structure?

Tags: python, fastapi

This is specifically to FastAPI & Jinja2Templates (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/) . If the directory of the templates & static files are within the python script directory it all works. But if the directory structure is outside the script, then it is NOT picking up

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
p06_dir="../artefacts/p06"
templates_dir=p06_dir + '/templates'
static_dir=p06_dir + '/static'
# Prints the directory correctly and files accessible
print(static_dir)

# Below fails
# RuntimeError: Directory 'static' does not exist
app.mount(static_dir, StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
# Below also fails
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=templates_dir)
```

```
.
├── artefacts
│   └── p06
│       └── static
│           ├── p06.css
│           └── vue.js
└── software
    └── api.py
```

if I use normal python3 sys module and OS module, all works but when it comes to FastApi, it is not finding the directory structure. Does anyone know a sample of FAstAPI/Jinja2Templates which uses templates externally?

Comment: You've used `static_dir` in the wrong location; the first parameter is where it's mounted in the web path (i.e. '/static'), while the parameter to `StaticFiles` is the directory on disk.

Comment: ah. thanks for that.  (moderator's if you can please close the question based on above answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used static_dir in the wrong location; the first parameter is where it's mounted in the web path (i.e. '/static'), while the parameter to StaticFiles is the directory on disk.

The correct syntax would be:

```
app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory=static_dir), name='static')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code, the file structure looks like:

```
|   api.py
|
+---static
|   |
|   +---css
|   |   \---bootswatch
|   |
|   +---geo_json
|   |
|   \---js
```

And in `api.py` I used:

```
this_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)

api.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=os.path.join(this_directory, "static")))
```

Comment: hi mate, in your example the directory structure is still within api.py . I've put the snapshot of my directory structure